# Embed video in SharePoint Content Editor WebPart - code?

Tags: html, sharepoint, video, embed

I've tried this:

```
 <EMBED style="WIDTH: 209px; HEIGHT: 196px" pluginspage=http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/ src=../Documents/filename.wmv width=209 height=196 type=application/x-mplayer2 controller="false" SHOWSTATUSBAR="0" AUTOPLAY="0">
```

But it just plays the sound and shows up with a green square - how do I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

The freeware program http://www.videohelp.com/tools/VideoInspector is useful for seeing what codecs the video requires.

Answer (score 0):

THis sounds like a codec issue. HAve you installed all needed codecs?

Comment: I don't know how to detect but the site already has another movie working fine, can I somehow find out the settings for that one and try to make it likewise